# how to run cygwin script in powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, cygwin

I am trying to run a cygwin script in powershell. How can I do that?

I tried giving full path of the scripts followed by args . it isnt working 
example : /c/script/path/script args

Comment: I wouldn't expect a cygwin script (I assume you mean bash or another cygwin shell?) to run in PowerShell, just as I wouldn't expect it to work from Command Prompt.

Comment: Sharing the error messages (if any) that you get will be more helpful than simply saying "it doesn't work."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use either `/cygdrive/c/script/path/script` or `C:/script/path/script` (note the capital `C` and lack of leading slash in the latter path). Plus, need to run the script with the correct interpreter, e.g.:

```
& C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive/c/script/path/script ...
```

Comment: To run a single command run `C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "command here"`

Comment: What does that `&` mean when it's at the beginning of the line? Is that your PROMPT?

Answer (score 1):

Having cygwin installed with the ssh stuff and SCP utility you can simply issue:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\scp.exe /cygdrive/c/Users/YOU/Documents/file.txt root@remoteserver:/tmp/
```

I find above can marked solution becomes a bit too shortcoming as the bash profile is not quite the same as in a working cygwin bash environment.